Is it possible to replicate classic table spacing using CSS Grid?
I have a table with two columns, and multiple rows. One of the columns typically has more content than the other. I would like to replicate the behavior of an old fashioned table, where free space is allocated roughly in proportion to the amount of content in a cell, except using grid instead of table. I would prefer to use grid so that I can make the cells stack vertically on a narrow screen.
Using grid-template-columns: auto auto is close, but remaining space is split evenly, and I want the remaining space to be split at a 2:1 (or other) ratio. 2fr 1fr isn't right, and there's no such thing as 2auto 1auto.
I can't find any combination of CSS Grid styles that replicate the spacing of a classic table. But just using a table that overrides the display property at a certain screen size seems inelegant. Is there a way to do this using only CSS Grid?


table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid>* {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.grid0 {
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(100%) fit-content(100%);
}

.grid1 {
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.grid2 {
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.grid3 {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 2fr) minmax(auto, 1fr);
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  table.hacky,
  table.hacky tr,
  table.hacky tr td {
    display: block;
  }
}
<p>
My starter grid without using any extra space:
</p>
<div class="grid grid0">
  <div>
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div>
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
For reference, here is a classic table. Note how by default, the first column gets more free space due to having more content.
</p>
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td>
    This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </td>
  <td>
    Less content here
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
Attempt 1: Try using "grid-template-columns: auto auto;".
</p>
<div class="grid grid1">
  <div>
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div>
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
Attempt 2: Try using "grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;".
</p>
<div class="grid grid3">
  <div>
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div>
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
Attempt 3: Try using "grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 2fr) minmax(auto, 1fr);".
</p>
<div class="grid grid3">
  <div>
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div>
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
Attempt 4: Just use classic table, and change "display" below a certain breakpoint.
</p>
<table class="hacky" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td>
    This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </td>
  <td>
    Less content here
  </td>
</tr>
</table>




Here is my attemp using flexbox (I know OP mentionned grid) but I think you can easily achieve this using flex. The downside is that the grow rate are hardcoded and don't dynamically adapt to content. But this should achieve a 2:1 ratio


table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid> #first {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.grid> #second {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid1 {
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.grid2 {
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.grid3 {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 2fr) minmax(auto, 1fr);
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  table.hacky,
  table.hacky tr,
  table.hacky tr td {
    display: block;
  }
}
<p>
My attempt with flex
</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div id="first">
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div id="second">
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
For reference, here is a classic table. Note how by default, the first column gets more free space due to having more content.
</p>
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td>
    This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </td>
  <td>
    Less content here
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
Attempt 1: Try using "grid-template-columns: auto auto;".
</p>
<div class="grid grid1">
  <div>
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div>
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
Attempt 2: Try using "grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;".
</p>
<div class="grid grid3">
  <div>
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div>
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
Attempt 3: Try using "grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 2fr) minmax(auto, 1fr);".
</p>
<div class="grid grid3">
  <div>
  This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </div>
  <div>
  Less content here
  </div>
</div>
<p>
Attempt 4: Just use classic table, and change "display" below a certain breakpoint.
</p>
<table class="hacky" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td>
    This cell has more, more, more, more, more, more, more content
  </td>
  <td>
    Less content here
  </td>
</tr>
</table>




Hi @Symtox your solution indeed adds remaining space at a 2:1 ratio. However, I should have specified in my question that my table has multiple rows. I only showed one row for simplicity. But with multiple rows, there is no way for flexbox to enforce the same column widths for all rows. Hence why the solution probably ought to be grid or table based.

Sure, I should have think about it ^^', You should either maybe resort to media query and use an "old fashion table" either Js solution with that many requirements
